# How to get siblings using xpath of an existing element?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, appium

I am trying to use xpath to find an element through an existing element.

I can find the element if I just try to find it from the driver like this:

```
var x=driver.FindElementByXPath("//locatorhere/following-sibling::LOCATORHERE");
```

But when I do it like this, it won't work:

```
var element=driver.FindElementByXPath("//locatorhere");
var x=element.FindElementByXPath("/following-sibling::LOCATORHERE")
```

my question is how exactly can I get the element the second way?

Comment: What does your XML look like? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59220872/edit) your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Your leading slash in the `following-sibling` XPath is incorrect. Instead of:

```
var x=element.FindElementByXPath("/following-sibling::LOCATORHERE")
```

It should be:

```
var x=element.FindElementByXPath("following-sibling::LOCATORHERE")
```

You do not need the preceding `/` character when you are calling `element.FindElement()`, as the `/` is implicit. However, if you are writing in `following-sibling` into an **existing** XPath, then you **do** need to use the preceding slash.

For example, given the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <input> Text </input>
    <span> More Text </span>
</div>
```

If you get the `input` as such:

```
var input = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("div/input"));
```

Then you can get the `span` as such:

```
var span = input.FindElement(By.XPath("following-sibling::span"))
```

Notice how the XPath above **does not** use the preceding `/` in `following-sibling`. Now, if you wish to use `following-sibling` as part of a longer XPath, this changes a bit:

```
var span = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("div/input/following-sibling::span"))
```

Comment: People just like "start from the root" (`/` and `//`) soooo much for some reason.